# Need to count array data having dynamic id with incremeent

Tags: php

count in php on dynamic field with same id :

```
[item_sequence_0] => 1
[item_sequence_1] => 2
```

need to count item sequence :

i.e. `$a = count($data[item_sequence]);`

show that result required :

```
$a = 2
```

Comment: What stops you from realisation it by yourself?

Comment: Array
(
    [advert_id] => 6543210
    [subscriber_number] => 123456
    [item_id] => 11
    [item_code] => GQ
    [item_sequence_0] => 1
    [sub_item_code] => TITEM
    [item_sequence_1] => 2
    [seq] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [seq_code] => Array
        (
            [0] => NM
            [1] => APH
            [2] => AD
        )

    [Name] => 103
    [Address] => 2
    [Phone] => 66
    [etl] => 0
    [submit] => submit
)

Comment: I need to count item_sequence

Comment: `I need to count item_sequence` - it's not a question.

Comment: this is the input field

 <input type="hidden" name="item_sequence_<?php echo $n ?>" value="<?php echo $advert_edit_form_data[0][$n]['item_sequence_number']; ?>">

Comment: I don't see why you don't just use an array of elements from the type hidden, `name=item_sequence[]`.

Comment: oh! dave thanks a lot.. I also don't know y I didn' use this way stupid me thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
$a = count(preg_grep('~^item_sequence~', array_keys($data)));
```

Comment: did not know about preg grep. very useful.